# SQL Server : sort ranking list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns `ordernum`, `username`, and `amount`. I want to select its rows and show an additional column `expected`.

The rule for calculating the `expected` column is as follows:

- These rows same OrderNum value will be ranking again based on `amount` column (Desc order). I don't know how I can describe, but the expected result is shown below :(

I tried with `RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`, but have not been able to properly apply above algorithm.

This is my table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  ordernum INT,
  username NVARCHAR(30),
  amount MONEY
);
```

This is my table content:

```
+----------+----------+------------+
| ORDERNUM | USERNAME |   AMOUNT   |
+----------+----------+------------+
|        1 | test01   | 18382.5079 |
|        1 | test02   | 10476.0000 |
|        1 | test03   |  8128.0000 |
|        1 | test04   |  6680.0000 |
|        1 | test05   |  5388.9673 |
|        1 | test06   |  5356.0000 |
|       12 | test07   |  2806.0000 |
|       12 | test08   |  2806.0000 |
|       12 | test09   |  2806.0000 |
|       14 | test10   |  2530.0000 |
|       15 | test11   |  2330.0000 |
|       16 | test12   |  2183.0000 |
|       16 | test13   |  2182.0000 |
|       17 | test14   |  2000.0000 |
|       18 | test15   |  1621.0000 |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

And this is my expected result:

```
+----------+----------+------------+----------+
| ORDERNUM | USERNAME |   AMOUNT   | EXPECTED |
+----------+----------+------------+----------+
|        1 | test01   | 18382.5079 |        1 |
|        1 | test02   | 10476.0000 |        2 |
|        1 | test03   |  8128.0000 |        3 |
|        1 | test04   |  6680.0000 |        4 |
|        1 | test05   |  5388.9673 |        5 |
|        1 | test06   |  5356.0000 |        6 |
|       12 | test07   |  2806.0000 |       12 |
|       12 | test08   |  2806.0000 |       12 |
|       12 | test09   |  2806.0000 |       12 |
|       14 | test10   |  2530.0000 |       15 |
|       15 | test11   |  2330.0000 |       16 |
|       16 | test12   |  2183.0000 |       17 |
|       16 | test13   |  2182.0000 |       18 |
|       17 | test14   |  2000.0000 |       19 |
|       18 | test15   |  1621.0000 |       20 |
+----------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Here is a fiddle for the problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4014cb469a9ec8f57ded5a5e0e60adaf

Comment: add what you have tried with your sql scripts.

Comment: I've added my script create data

Comment: @ĐăngLưuTrần and whats the expected result?

Comment: you click "Image description" in my post, I need result in Expected col

Comment: Don't link to images. Paste the result as text in your request instead. And then **explain** what you want. By what **formula** do you want to calculate the `expect` column?

Comment: I added expected column in my script, you can copy my script and excute

Comment: And how do you get to these values? What is the rule? And why "can't" you use `ROW_NUMBER`? Do you get an error? If so, which? Or do you get wrong results? Or something else still?

Comment: And what is your DBMS? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: DBMS: SQL SERVER
Rule in Expected column: these rows same OrderNum value will be ranking again based on Amt column (Desc order). I dont know how i can describe, but I expected result in Expected col :(

Comment: Please check the following. It looks like the rule is: Order all rows by `ordernum, amount DESC, username`. The first row's `expected` value is its `ordernum`. Then go through the list row by row. If the next row has the same `ordernum` and the same amount, then give it the same `expected` value. If has the same `ordernum` and a lower amount, then give it the `expected` value incremented by 1. If it has another `ordernum` then give it the greater of the following two values: Either its `ordernum` or the last `expected` value plus the number of entries for the last `ordernum`.

Comment: I've edited your request. It only lacks the explanation now how to calculate the `expected` value. If my algorithm above is correct, then this is an iterative process (ie you cannot calculate a row's `expected` value without knowing the calculated `expected` value of the previous row. If you are selecting the whole table anyway, I'd suggest you write a program (with a programming language) to loop through your rows and calculate the values. If you want to do this in SQL instead you'd probably have to write a recursive query. (Or maybe a stored procedure; I don't know SQL Server enough to say.)

Comment: do you have anyway to help me :(

Comment: You haven't even answered whether my interpretation of the desired rule is correct. Please read my penultimate comment and tell us whether this is what you are after. If it is, then, in my last comment, I have suggested not to do this in SQL, but in a programming language. I suppose you are in the progress of writing an app or Website anyway, for after all SQL is just a means to get some data, not something users should be forced to deal with. It shouldn't be too difficult to loop through your data with a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
select
    OrderNum,
    Username,
    Amount,
    RANK() over (order by OrderNum) as Expected
from yourTable
```

Comment: it not simple, you can view my photo description